# Relative paths INSIDE file_get_contents result

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am loading a url into my page on my local server with PHP file_get_contents. It works fine but relative paths on the site I am pulling obviously fail and default to my localhost.

Does anyone have any advice on how I could swap relative paths of a page I am pulling to absolute ones?

Ive tried something like this but it fails...

```
$homepage = file_get_contents($theURL);
$homepage2 = str_replace($homepage, "/images", $theURL + '/images');
echo $homepage2;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're arguments for `str_replace` are in the wrong order.

Instead of

```
$homepage2 = str_replace($homepage, "/images", $theURL + '/images');
```

You should be doing

```
$homepage2 = str_replace("/images", $theURL + '/images', $homepage);
```

http://php.net/str_replace

`str_replace(search, replace, subject)`